# Using GLEE w/ includes?

Tags: opengl

How do you implement GLEE in your code so that it loads extensions used within included files?

For example, I have a windows build environment using cygwin and GCC, and am linking to the libraries for GLEE, GLUT, and opengl32.

The includes in my main file are ..

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <GL/GLee.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include "SampleUtils.h"
#include "LineShaders.h"
```

**SampleUtils.h** declares methods that utilize OpenGL extensions, such as glCreateShader, which are implemented in SampleUtils.cpp. But when I attempt to build these files, the extensions are undeclared. I've tried a couple of different approaches.

Such as including in SampleUtils

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
```

which results in undeclared errors

```
#include <GL/GLee.h>
```

which throws a long list of errors that seem to relate to the fact that GLEE has already been included.

I can load the same extensions by implementing these methods in the main file, but can't get them to load from an included file. How is this dealt with?

Comment: Are you building for Linux, Win32, or something else? Also, GLee seems to be abandoned, so you may want to go for [something else](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Extension_Loading_Library).

Comment: Win32. Genpfault set me straight. WIN32 wasn't defined for the included files. But as you've probably picked up from my other question, I'm also working w/ OpenGL ES in Android. The Android environment was preconfigured, and now I'm hitting a lot of basic issues like this trying to set-up the same in Windows. Lots to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in GLee.h:55

```
#ifdef WIN32
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <GL/gl.h>
#elif defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__APPLE_CC__)
    #define GL_GLEXT_LEGACY
    #include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#else // GLX
    #define __glext_h_  /* prevent glext.h from being included  */
    #define __glxext_h_ /* prevent glxext.h from being included */
    #define GLX_GLXEXT_PROTOTYPES
    #include <GL/gl.h>
    #include <GL/glx.h>
#endif
```

Wherever you `#include "GLee.h"` you *don't* have to `#include` `gl.h`, `glext.h`, or `windows.h`.

Comment: Yes. That's what I'd expected from the docs, but if I only include Glee.h in SampleUtils, g++ throws a long list of errors, such as.. /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../include/w32api/GL/GLee.h:827: error: `XID' does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../include/w32api/GL/GLee.h:832: error: `XID' does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../include/w32api/GL/GLee.h:836: error: `Bool' does not name a type etc..

Comment: I've also tried removing all GL and/or Glee headers from the included files, in case these are inherited from the parent. But this only results in undeclared errors, as you'd expect. So GL headers in the included files result in errors, the Glee header alone results in errors, and no GL or Glee headers also results in errors. Which approach is supposed to be implemented in the includes? - #include <GL/GLee.h>?

Comment: @olo: If it's hitting line 827 then the header is taking the GLX path, which means `WIN32` isn't defined.  Try adding `-DWIN32` on your `gcc` invocations, or manually `#define WIN32` before `#include`ing GLEE.  In the future putting the compiler error log(s) in your question would be helpful.

Comment: You're right. Defining WIN32 and including Glee.h in the included implementation file works. I'm guessing that the windows.h include accomplished the same elsewhere, because by removing it I was able to provoke the same errors. Thanks genpfault.